# What does SqlCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand Create?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

So if I want to update my DataSource I use

```
selCmd = New SqlCommand("Select foo from bar", New SqlConnection("baz"))
da = New SqlDataAdapter(selCmd)
cmdB = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
...'User changes some Data
da.UpdateCommand = cmdB.GetUpdateCommand
da.Update(testDS, "testtable")
```

Does `GetUpdateCommand` create its own connection instance or does it use `da.SelectCommand.Connection`?

Thank you

Comment: It creates an UPDATE command. It uses `da.SelectCommand.Connection`.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/Common/DBCommandBuilder.cs,951644d413015a4e take a look :)

Comment: You asked us questions that you could easily answer for yourself. All you had to do was call the method and examine the result.

Comment: Calling `GetUpdateCommand` is generally pointless. Once you have create the command builder, just call `Update` on the data adapter and it will work. You only need to get the commands and assign them explicitly if you intend to modify them, e.g. enrol them in a transaction.